# How to tell when a youtube video is played with Youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm currently calling a video using the youtube API using:

```
<div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
</div>

var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
swfobject.embedSWF(
    "http://www.youtube.com/v/TEHWDA_6e3M?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
    "ytapiplayer", 
    "960", 
    "540", 
    "8", 
    null, 
    null, 
    params, 
    atts
);
```

However, I need to have something to happen when the video is played.

I've been trying to use this:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Adding_event_listener
Like this:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
```

Although I have never worked with javascript at this level nor an API before.

Comment: i tried to wire up youtube a few weeks ago and was having pretty much the same issue.

Comment: What is happening when you play the video, then? Does the error console show any errors that the API might be throwing?

Comment: Here's a fiddle from an older stackoverflow question that's pretty similar ... compare the code there to what you're doing and see if you find what's wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/masiha/tFQEN/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [iframe Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for new development.

The [Getting Started example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) on that page illustrates embedding a video and handling the event that's fired when playback starts.